# I need a small NuGet POC, to understand how to consume a NuGet package in Visual studio?

Tags: package, nuget, nuget-package

I am new to Nugets. By using any existed NuGet packages i want to know how to use it. to understand the advantage of Nuget.

Comment: What's your question actually?

Comment: I need to Create a POC for how to consume Packages in Nugets? What ever the available Nuget package is fine. i need to show that how to use nuget package

Answer (score 0):

Easiest thing you can do to get a NuGet package, is go to http://nuget.org/packages, click on any package and then click on the download link to download to the package to your machine. You can install [NuGet Package Explorer](https://npe.codeplex.com/) to drill into the package or change the extension to zip and open it yourself